# Why is the file size smaller than what I calculated?

Tags: bit-manipulation

The question is the conversion from an animation to a video file with the following attributes:

Frame rate:24 fps

Resolution:320*240 pixels

Color depth:24 bits

Length of video: 60s

Bit rate: 500kbps

I calculated that the file size should be 24*60*320*240*3=316MB (frame rate* resolution* colordepth / 3 * resolution), but the answer stated that the actual file size was just 500kbps*60=3.5 MB due to file compression.I do not understand how this works.

Comment: The compression is not lossless. If you compress with a target of 500kbps, the compression algorithm reduces the quality of the video until only 500kb information are required for each video second.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm relatively new to this and I don't really understand it thank you.

Comment: I’m quite sure that the depth is not 24 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 kilo **bits** per second for 60 seconds. The information is compressed to fit within the bit rate in a possibly lossy format.

8 bits = 1 byte.

So its $500 / 8 \times 60$ kilobytes.

Thats 3750 kilobytes.